# Casting variable or saving at first?

Tags: android, json

I am developing an Android app that gets data from a web. Just wondering which way is the best, or at least which one is a good programming practice? or maybe both are good? Both ways work, just want to do it with good practices.

This is the first way:

```
JSONObject address_dest = dispatch_info.getJSONObject("address_dest");
int dest_addressid = address_dest.getInt("address_id");
dest_disptach.setAddressId(dest_addressid);
```

This is the second way:

```
JSONObject address_dest = dispatch_info.getJSONObject("address_dest");
dest_disptach.setAddressId(address_dest.getInt("address_id"));
```

Comment: Either way is fine.  Use the first if you need to use the value below as well, the second if you don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second one is better since you use one extra reference at first one. But they are identical.

Comment: that's wrong. the call to the method `getJSONObject` will always give you a temporary reference. Temporary expressions and local variables need the same space.

Comment: int dest_addressid = address_dest.getInt("address_id"); is the extra here. You are writing the getInt reference to dest_addressid reference. dest_addressid reference is totally useless if you don't plan to use it again.

Comment: sorry, that's what i meant: the `getInt` will give you a temporary variable anyway. The `getInt` will probably not be inlined by the jvm, since it's calling to the json's internal map (so its not a getter).
Also, I would be cautious calling the variable "useless" - it improves readability (ok, not in this case, because the variable name is not readable at all...). What I mean is: there is no performance or memory difference.

Comment: It really depend where you use it. If this was going to be a global variable or a temp int made by the system. The temp is better. And realistically you would have to call it a few million times to every see any noticeable difference.

Comment: Well I always thought that when you use getInt, you create a temporary reference to the real memory of the integer, and by creating int dest_adressid, you create another reference that showing the first temporary reference that you created.

Answer (score 2):

If readability is important to you, go for the first way.

If you prefer less lines of code, go for the second way.

Either way is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I really have AN AMAZING idea. But I would figure the second one, purely off the fact that you would be using less in the application by having one less saved int.

EDIT:
Pre Edit:
"I really have no idea"